# SelectAll button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. I want to check all the check boxes on button click. How do I do this using JavaScript only?

```
<div id="blocked_list_add_website_help_text">
    <button type="button" id="blockSelectAll" class="secondary">Select All</button>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="box1" />Box1
<input type="checkbox" value="box2" />Box2
<input type="checkbox" value="box3" />Box3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure JS:

```
document.getElementById("blockSelectAll").onclick = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            inputs[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**<kbd>[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65N6D/)</kbd>**

Answer (score 3):

Using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.getElementById("blockSelectAll").onclick = function(){
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

    for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
        checkboxes[i].checked = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just try this

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="blockSelectAll" onclick="checkAll()" class="secondary">Select All</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkAll() {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');    
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             checkboxes[i].setAttribute('checked', true) // Or inputs[i].checked = true;
         }
     }
 }
```

[<kbd>**Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/erfBs/1/)

Comment: No need to create a `new Array()` first

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checker() {
     checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
          checkbox.checked = true;
}
</script>
<div id="blocked_list_add_website_help_text">
    <button type="button" id="blockSelectAll" class="secondary" onclick=checker() >Select All</button>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="box1" />Box1
<input type="checkbox" value="box2" />Box2
<input type="checkbox" value="box3" />Box3
```